# insert image with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-insert-post

When processing the form i want the values to be inserted into the custom post type `products`.

Here is what i have done so far

```
$art_title = $_POST['art_title'];

$i = 0;
foreach($art_title as $value) {
$art_title = $_POST['art_title'][$i];
$art_width = $_POST['art_width'][$i];
$art_height = $_POST['art_height'][$i];
$art_price = $_POST['art_price'][$i];
$art_creation_date = $_POST['art_creation_date'][$i];

   // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $art_title,
        'post_status'   => 'draft',    
        'post_type' => 'products'
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'art_upload[$i]', $pid );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

$i++;
}
```

I used media_handle_upload along with the post id but this isn't working.

What i want to know is how do i insert these $_POST values into the custom post type `products` along with the image as `product_image`?

The custom post type is the woocommerce `products`.

Any help greatly appreciated.  An example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should be correctly creating the post inside your Products post type.

You're missing the bit that updates the post meta holding the image. Assuming the meta_key is `product_image`, then running this on success should do:

```
update_post_meta( $pid, 'product_image', $attachment_id );
```

on a side note: don't forget to run [wp_generate_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) and [wp_update_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_attachment_metadata) after you upload the image.

Comment: thanks for this, how do i find out the woocommerce meta_keys/custom field names?

Comment: they probably have some documentation for this, but if all else fails, this plugin should help you find it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/database-peek/